# Не работает регулярное выражение с вещественными числами

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
result = re.findall(r'^[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$', 'Half Price Was £1.75 Now 87p')
print(result)
```

Код написан на питоне. Мне нужно, чтобы из строки извлекались числа 1.75 и 87, а в ответе просто пустой список выдается. В чем ошибка?

Comment: `^` и `$` убери... тебе же не полностью строку матчить надо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метасимволы `^` и `$` находят соответственно начало и конец строки. Таким образом, регулярное выражение в вопросе может найти совпадения в таких строках, как `123,56` или `123.89434`, но не `123,56 руб.` или `Значение: 123.89434`.

Используйте

```
print(re.findall(r'[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+', 'Half Price Was £1.75 Now 87p'))
```

См. [Python-демо](https://ideone.com/jxtv1q), а также [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/lCJOW4/1).

**Подробности**

- `[0-9]*` - 0+ цифр
- `[.,]?` - 1 или 0 точек или запятых
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ цифр.

Обратите внимание на то, что данное выражение найдёт такие совпадения, как `0.567`, `.5678`, `124,567`, `,467`. Если ноль перед десятичной дробью обязателен, нужно использовать `r'[0-9]+(?:[,.][0-9]+)?'`.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [163]: import re

In [203]: result = re.findall(r'\d+.?\d+|\d+', 'Half Price Was £1.75 Now 87p 1')

In [204]: result
Out[204]: ['1.75', '87', '1']
```